# Exponential on itself series converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, induction

[image: Here is the question. I sent it as a image since I could not find how to write a1 as below.]

My first approach is that I need to use induction on that. However the problem is that what is the upper bound limit for this series?

Also, let's say we showed that it converges. Doesn't it directly imply that that convergence point is the limit of the series? What is the difference?

Note: This is non-grading homework question. Since it is explained in image, I feel that I need to explain.

Comment: "Convergence point" is the same as "limit." But the reason why they are separate questions is because sometimes it is possible to prove that a sequence converges without determining what the convergence point is.

Comment: Alright, now I see that. It is asking me that if I can find that point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, $a_n\leqslant2$. This can be proved by induction: $a_1=\sqrt2<2$ and if $a_n<2$, then $a_{n+1}=\sqrt2^{a_n}<\sqrt2^2=2$.

On the other hand, $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is increasing: it is not hard to prove that if $x\in(0,2)$, then $\sqrt2^x>x$.

Since $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is increasing and bounded, it converges. But this information does not tell you what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

Comment: The limit must satisfy $ L = \sqrt{2}^L$ and $L=2$ satisfies this relation, so the limit must be $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know *that* the sequence converges, what can you infer about the actual *value* of $a:=\lim a_n$?
Since $f\colon x\mapsto \sqrt2^x$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$, we must have $$\tag1a=\sqrt 2^a.$$ As $f$ is also strictly increasing, $(1)$ cannot have more than one solution. One (and hence *the*) solution we can immediately spot is $$a=2.$$